# Replace the alphanumeric, numeric values with empty space

Tags: linux, shell, awk

File looks like this:

```
1234567890|asdfg|werty|asfgtr21|12345|zxcv=sdf|zsde=1234
2345678901|we1|sd1=12df|werty|dfghj|sdf=fgh|hjkl
```

And the required output is:

```
1234567890|asdfg|werty|||zxcv=sdf|
2345678901|||werty|dfghj|sdf=fgh|hjkl
```

Comment: better read [ask] and provide some of your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf $1"|"; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i !~ /.*[0-9].*/) printf $i;  printf "|"; } printf "\n"}' file
```

Same oneliner split & indented to understand it better:

```
awk -F'|' '{
    printf $1"|";
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i !~ /.*[0-9].*/)
            printf $i;
        printf "|"
    }
    printf "\n"}' file
```

Comment: answering a no-effort question with a one-liner without any explanation is not likely to raise the quality of the page at all. Also, you may want to use `FS` and `ORS`, so that instead of `printf "|"` or `printf "\n"` you can say `printf "%s", FS` or even `print ""`.

Comment: Hi Arnon, Thank you... The solution works as required

Comment: wanting to get an op's so called "effort" for a simple one liner awk question in not likely to raise the quality of the page either. It's true, stackoverflow is not a code writing service, but a one liner is hardly code, and the op's effort won't help anyone write it. The indented example explains itself pretty well. Your suggestion sounds good, you are welcome to edit my answer and add another option.

Comment: No, I won't edit your question. Also, I don't understand the downvote because it is not a bad answer. And again about the quality: current question with current answer is not likely to help anyone else than the person asking: he got an easy hack without any effort, so he will probably do the same next time.

Comment: @fedorqui It's a pretty bad answer, it could be written better and the lack of explanation makes it worse.